# How can my site become public to the internet when i have done this actions:

Tags: azure, joomla, web, cname

1. Created virtual machine in Azure.
2. Added HTTP endpoint on public port 80, private port 80
3. Installing from Terminal into Azure Virtual Machine: Ubuntu 14.0.4, Apache, phpMyAdmin and my Joomla Site.

I can acces my site with IpAdress/myJoomlaSite but i want to show my site to internet like www.myJoomlasite.com.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to (in a nutshell):

1. Create the domain and a CNAME for the URI we provide to you at the portal (websitename.azurewebsites.net)
2. Add the domain to the portal so Azure App Service knows what to do with it.

More information and detailed steps you can find on [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)